# How to GET data through HTTP GET requests from Angular to a locally running Spring Boot rest API on port 8080?

Tags: json, angular, spring-boot, api, get

I did use the angular HttpClient. It could GET data from various APIs available online, but can't GET data from my spring boot RESTful API running from HTTP://localhost:8080/users

Could anyone tell what maybe the issue, and suggest some possible fixes?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss'],
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Object;
  http: HttpClient;
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  postdetail(): void {
    this.http
      .get('http://localhost:8080/users')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Errors would help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService} from 'path to api service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss'],
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  data: MyDetailInterface;
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}


  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.apiService.postDetail().subscribe((data) => {
    this.data = data;
  });
  }

}
```

Create a service **api.service.ts** instead of making the http call directly from your component:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export const BASE_URI: string = "http://localhost:8080/"


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  postDetail(): Observable<MyDetailInterface> {
    return this.httpClient.get<MyDetailInterface>(BASE_URI + "users");
  }

}
```

Create the MyDetailInterface interface:

```
export interface MyDetailInterface {
    id: number;
    ....

   
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Anyhow, I had to resolve a CORS issue. Gratitude!